# How to merge two lists in python?

Tags: python

I have the following two lists:

```
lista = ['a', 'b']
listb = ['c', 'd']
```

And I want the output list like this:

```
res = [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']]
```

My solution is

```
arr = np.array([lista, listb]).T
res = arr.tolist()
```

Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: what happens if the lists have different lengths? how should the result be then? in your example if `listb=['b', 'd', 'f']`  should the result be `[['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['f']]` or  `[['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['', 'f']]` ?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Should terminate with an error.

Comment: If you want just a flat list result like `['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']`, you just need to use the `+` operator: `res = lista + listb`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[list(a) for a in zip(lista, listb)]
```

Whether this is simplier might be subjective, but it is one of the options for sure.

Comment: Isn't easier to just do `list(zip(lista, listb))`?

Comment: @accdias No, because then inner objects will be tuples and not lists.

Comment: Oh! I see your point. :-D

Answer (score 2):

You can declare `res` variable and pass both lists as arguments. It is a lot simpler. Also, don't use `list` as a variable name as it is a built-it  `function` name

```
res = []
for i in range(len(lista)):
    temp = [lista[i], listb[i]]

    res.append(temp)
```

You can also use list comprehension which is faster and more transparent

```
res = [[lista[x], listb[x]] for x in range(len(lista))]
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants.

Comment: "And I want the output list like this: res = [['a', **'c'**], [**'b'**, 'd']]"

Comment: @matszwecja my bad, edited and posted correct solution